# ios - How to use ExtAudioFileConvert sample in a new project

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, caf, extaudiofile

All I wanted was to read a caf file and write it to another file, in the hopes that perhaps I can manipulate it such as combine multiple files into one, or trimming. So I found Apples's own **iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest** Sample, which looks very challenging but I figured once I take the pieces into my own project, then I can play with it, this proved to be rather cumbersome.

Now, after a few sleepless nights of digging for information and lots trial and errors runs;
I believed I have managed to use the the **iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest** Sample in my own project. I thought I would post this to save a fellow coder some sleep.

Steps:

- Added the **iPublicUtility** folder and the **ExtAudioFileConvert.cpp** file from the **iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest** sample to my project.
- Renamed the extension of the 3 new .cpp files to .mm (the .h files stay the same). This allows xcode to view the cpp files as objective c++ files.

  - ExtAudioFileConvert.mm
  - iPublicUtility/CAStreamBasicDescription.mm
  - iPublicUtility/CAXException.mm
- In my **myViewController.m** (UIViewController) class that plans to call the 
  `DoConvertFile(sourceURL, destinationURL, outputFormat, sampleRate);` method, I added one line to make the DoConvertFile method visible

  `extern OSStatus DoConvertFile(CFURLRef sourceURL, CFURLRef destinationURL, OSType outputFormat, Float64 outputSampleRate);`
- Also renamed myViewController.m to **myViewController.mm** because it's using a .cpp file to make the convertFile method call
- In my project setting under Targets / Build Settings, I searched for the key "Header Search Paths" and added the following for it's value **/Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/ $(inherited)** without this line the compiler would give me over 30 errors, such as *'DebugPrintfFile*' was not declared in this scope*
- I noticed that the sample also has code in the app delegate

  - so I copied the code of the 2 methods directly from the sample's appDelegate into my own appDelegate, namly

    - `static void interruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruption)`
    - `static void propertyListener(void *inClientData, AudioSessionPropertyID inID, UInt32 inDataSize, const void *inData)`
  - and added the the following 4 lines right after the original `#import` statement

    - #import "CAXException.h"
    - `extern void ThreadStateInitalize();`
    - `extern void ThreadStateBeginInterruption();`
    - `extern void ThreadStateEndInterruption();`
  - of course also added the code from the samples `applicationDidFinishLaunching` into my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
  - and once again renamed my appDelegate.m to appDelegate.mm

---

Now when I compile I get no errors and runtime only works if I comment out the assert in ExtAudioFileConvert.mm

```
    // in this sample we should never be on the main thread here
    assert(![NSThread isMainThread]);
```

Also at startup I receive an error which is not causing any issues, but I'd prefer to remove it. Anyone ?

```
    Error: couldn't set audio category (-50)
```

which seems to be coming from this call in my appDelegate

```
    // our default category -- we change this for conversion and playback appropriately
    UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbientSound;
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(audioCategory), &audioCategory), "couldn't set audio category");
```

---

Other than these warnings/errors, I can write/convert a caf file :).
I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: you are running iPhone ,not simulator

Comment: did you ever resolve it? I am having the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jose, I haven't resolved this warning, but nevertheless, the project went on the back burner. In the meantime, I published two other Apps :)